# Make Thunderbird forget password

Tags: email, passwords, thunderbird

I use Thunderbird as my mail client under Linux Mint 20.2. I desire that my password is not remembered, but that I will be prompted for the password whenever I open Thunderbird. (Ideally with the possibility to use the password manager KeePassXC in that prompt.)

Since Thunderbird didn't do as I wished, I removed my e-Mail account from Thunderbird and then added it again. During that process, I unticked the box "remember password".
However, after closing the Thunderbird window and then opening Thunderbird again, I was not prompted for the password, and all e-Mails were displayed. I am also not prompted when I check for incoming mail.
I tried closing Thunderbird, shutting down the computer, then starting the computer and Thunderbird, but still I was not prompted for the password.

Where can I set Thunderbird to not remember my password? It is probably simple, but I don't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Linux version of Thunderbird, this should be found in `Edit` > `Preferences`

For the Windows version, this should be under the menu option for `Tools` > `Options`

---

From there, there should be a tab on the left labeled `Privacy & Security`
One of the sections near the top should be `Passwords`.

Make sure that `Use a master password` is checked. You will be prompted for this once per session (whenever you open Thunderbird, and mail is retrieved for the first time).

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I can not find `Options` in the dropdown which opened after I clicked `Tools`.

Comment: Right, sorry about that... the Linux version simply has it under Preferences (answer has been edited)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is actually not what I was looking for, but better. I was looking for a way so that Thunderbird would prompt me for the password of each mail account. Your suggestion to use the Master password fits my usecase better. (I wasn't aware of this possibility when formulating the question.)

Comment: Yeah, if you want it to prompt you every time, you simply cannot have it save the password (and I'm not sure that is an option in TB, as then it would prompt you for every mail retrieval!)

Comment: I did not want Thunderbird to save the password(s) in the first place. And I am also sure that there must be a functionality like I describe in my question, because in a former setup of Thunderbird, I was prompted for the password whenever I wanted to get messages for a given account for the first time of a Thunderbird session.